# Why does garageband does not detect the instrument plugin I installed?

Tags: daw, plug-ins, piano, garageband, imac

I am trying to use this particular piano plugin on my GarageBand DAW on a Macbook.
http://www.supremepiano.com/index.html?piano1.html
I downloaded it, unarchived (unzipped) it and installed the .pkg file. 
Now I understand, that if the install worked properly, on my Macintosh HD, under Library --> Plugins, I should see this Plugin, but I dont.

I also tried opening GB, creating a track(software instrument), open Smart Controls and click on Plugins. I don't see the plugin I downloaded, only the default Apple Plugins.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: What's the O/S and word length of the plugin? make sure that GB has been restarted and that the O/S supports the word length that the plugin uses.

Comment: Thank you. 64 bit. How can i check that the O/s supports the word length?

Comment: Mojave was the last O/S to support 32-bit executables.

Comment: @Timinycricket: Thank you. There is no component file. There is a .pkg file which is an executable. When clicked, it installs the plugin.

Comment: It comes as both AU [component] & VST - this is the installer opened to inspect https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFddv.png & the installer demo video shows then using it in Logic, which is Garage Band's big brother, so it should work. i'd ask the company, or re-watch the video, check the manual. Path to AUs is /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/ so check if it's there.

Answer (score 2):

Garageband supports Audio Units (AU).  If the plugin only supports VST format, it won’t appear.